# Vocabulary terms deleted but still visible

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I work on a D7 website where some taxonomy terms were created and then deleted.

I’ve build a search form with views based on taxonomy terms (filter criterion: Content: Term name (field_term_name)) and i see some "deleted" terms in filter exposed to visitor.

I’ve check directly in DB and it appears that these datas (which should be completely deleted) are still in `taxonomy_term_data`.

I do not see these terms in the Drupal admin but I can however still see them in the database, and I can open them directly using the tid in the Drupal interface.

My experience with Drupal let me think that is not a good idea to delete them directly in DB. So how can I proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

`taxonomy_term_data` is the canonical location for term data so it sounds like there might be other issues going on (a broken admin display, caching, DB corruption via orphaned parent/child term, we can only guess).

If you want a safe way to remove taxonomy, invoke the [taxonomy API functions](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/7.x) (they are the same tools the admin interface is using) via Devel, `drush eval`, or some other dev tool where you can execute arbitrary PHP that uses these functions to remove your desired terms:

For example:

```
$my_bad_tids = [1, 2, 3];
$terms = taxonomy_term_load_multiple($my_bad_tids);
foreach ($terms as $term) { 
  taxonomy_term_delete($term->tid);
}
```