# Taxonomy term deleted but still visible (again)

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I have seen [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/258085/vocabulary-terms-deleted-but-still-visible), but it seems that the behaviour in my case is even worse.

I have a text field with custom autocomplete which connects to an external service to get terms, and then it creates them if they do not exist in Drupal. Since I am in a early development phase, I am constantly creating and deleting terms. I re-enabled the standard autocomplete widget for a test, and I found that it shows all the terms I had created and deleted! I checked in `taxonomy_term_field_data`, and of course they are present there.

The terms were created with the following code:

```
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;

[...]

Term::create(array(
  'vid' => 'my_taxonomy',
  'field_codetype' => $codeType,
  'field_mycode' => $myCode,
  'field_codedate' => $codeDate,
  'field_denominazione' => $denominazione,
  'name' => $denominazione,
))->save() ;
```

and were deleted from the admin interface. Maybe I am missing some mandatory field?

Comment: How did you delete them through the UI? Presumably by submitting the form at /taxonomy/term/[tid]/delete?

Comment: Yes. If I am not mistaken, it's the only way to delete a term from the admin interface, isn't it?

Comment: It's the most common but there could be others, worth checking at least. When you delete a term and visit the vocab page again, is the term still listed? If not then it has been deleted, and your issue is likely to be caching

Comment: The terms are not present in the vocabulary. Which cache are you talking about? I regularly issue `druch cr`, if I understand correctly that should clear all caches, correct? Just to be on the safe side, I also cleaned the browser's cache, and I event uninstalled and reinstalled my module, but the terms are still there...

Comment: It's not really a serious problem, in production each term should be created at the first use and only be referenced afterwards, I also plan to set up a unique constraint using the Validation API; but since I am both developing a project _and_ learning Drupal at the same time, I would like to understand what's going on.

Comment: Understandably :) The reason I'm thinking cache is that you're using an entity autocomplete widget, which is connected to entity storage, and the vocab page is also getting its data from the same storage. So if there's an inconsistency between the two, that's where I'd be inclined to look. Are you behind a reverse proxy? I'd also be inclined to reload the edit form with the browser dev tools network tab open and "Disable cache" checked, and try again, if only to 100% rule out browser cache

Comment: Is it possible the terms exist in another vocabulary? Just a thought.

Comment: Thank you @Clive, I did as you suggested and I saw nothing strange: when I select elements on the autocomplete field (the original one, not my modified version) a call to a Drupal URL is done, and the list of terms is returned, both the latest one created and the deleted ones. Cache was disabled in the dev tools, and I am not behind a revers proxy. So, I would say that the problem is not the browser cache...

Comment: Continuing to work on my project, I noticed that terms now regularly disappear from `taxonomy_term_field_data` either when I delete them from the admin interface or when I uninstall the module. So, apparently the terms I see in the table and that appear in the autocomplete list are residual from some other errors in the past. The strange thing is that they appear in the autocomplete list, but not in the admin interface. Anyway, I am afraid it may be difficult to reconsctruct what happened; if no suggestion will come, I will simply start again with a fresh installation.